# Part of javascript not working in IE8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

The below querySelector functionality not working in IE8,but same is working int IE 11.

Code:

```
    $(document).ready(
        function() {

            $(window).load(
                    function() {
                        var fiveMinutes = 60 * 15, display = document
                                .querySelector('#time');
                        startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
                    });

            function startTimer(duration, display) {
                var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
                setInterval(function() {
                    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

                    if (--timer < 0) {
                        timer = duration;
                    }
                }, 1000);
            }
```

HTML Code:

```
   <div >
    <div id ="timer">
        Next Refresh will be in <span id="time">05:00</span> minutes!
    </div>
    <div>
```

Comment: If you use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to look up compatibility, it says that IE8 can use `querySelector`, but if you follow up with [CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) you'll see that `querySelector` is limited in IE8. Use `document.getElementById` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HTMLElement#textContent` isn't supported by IE8.

You're using jQuery, let's use jQuery to work around that — half the reason it was created originally was to deal with browser inconsistencies (only half, and that's no longer its primary reason for being).

The minimal change is to change

```
display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;
```

to

```
$(display).text(minutes + ":" + seconds);
```

---

You have a couple of other issues with that code. In particular, you're falling prey to [*The Horror of Implicit Globals*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html) — declare your variables! And you can use jQuery to find the element instead of using `querySelector`. So:

```
$(document).ready(
    function() {

        $(window).load(
            function() {
                var fiveMinutes = 60 * 15,
                    display = $("#time");            // Use jQuery to look this up
                startTimer(fiveMinutes, display);
            });

        function startTimer(duration, display) {
            var timer = duration,
                minutes, seconds;
            setInterval(function() {
                // Note the variable declarations
                var minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
                var seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

                display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);      // Use text() to set the text

                if (--timer < 0) {
                    timer = duration;
                }
            }, 1000);
        }
    }
);
```